# invalid_grant trying to get OAuth token from Google

Tags: google-api

I keep getting an `invalid_grant` error on trying to get an OAuth token from Google to connect to their contacts API. All the information is correct and I have triple-checked this so I'm kind of stumped.

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue? I have tried setting up a different client ID for it but I get the same result. I have tried connecting many different ways including trying the force authentication, but still the same result.

Comment: for me the problem was on google credentials page...i created another one...and solved the problem....

Comment: I had this issue recently and it also happens when you try to request the first access token with refresh token again, then the invalid_grant also shows up.. I solved it by resetting the secret and then cathing the first tokens on the first request.. if I failed and tried again I would get the invalid_grant again.. first time you need to catch the tokens save and then only refresh with refresh token otherwuse you are "invalid"

Comment: @Sagan care to explain your process and sequence again?

Comment: @MikeyB a bit late but sure, if you are getting the invalid grant error due to the same reason like me then you solve it by resetting the secret key in the google console and go through the token generation flow again with the new secret key, but don't forget to save the refresh token which is only generated once, then you can generate access tokens using the refresh token.

Comment: @Sagan but this you will be doing again in the next 7 days when it is revoked again. Is there a permanent or rather a long lasting way of doing this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I didn't explicitly request "offline" access when sending the user to the OAuth "Do you want to give this app permission to touch your stuff?" page.

Make sure you specify access_type=offline in your request.

Details here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

(Also: I think Google added this restriction in late 2011.  If you have old tokens from before then, you'll need to send your users to the permission page to authorize offline use.)

Comment: @Adders I agree. I set `access_type` to `offline`, this error still happens.

Comment: Go through this https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization documentation and read everything to implement

Comment: @slideshowp2. were you able to resolve this? i am still getting this issue with acccess_type being offline

Comment: For this api https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
I used 5 things and it worked
client_id, client_secret, grant_type=authorization_code, code, redirect_uri

but before that in oauth api, access_type=offline & response_type=code should be there

Answer (score 179):

Although this is an old question, it seems like many still encounter it - we spent days on end tracking this down ourselves.

In the OAuth2 spec, "invalid_grant" is sort of a catch-all for all errors related to invalid/expired/revoked tokens (auth grant or refresh token).

For us, the problem was two-fold:

1. **User has actively revoked access to our app**
   Makes sense, but get this: 12 hours after revocation, *Google stops sending* the error message in their response:
   `“error_description” : “Token has been revoked.”`
   It's rather misleading because you'll assume that the error message is there at all times which is not the case. You can check whether your app still has access at the [apps permission page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).
2. **User has reset/recovered their Google password**
   In December 2015, [Google changed](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/12/increased-account-security-via-oauth2.html) their default behaviour so that password resets for non-Google Apps users would automatically revoke all the user's apps refresh tokens. On revocation, the error message follows the same rule as the case before, so you'll only get the "error_description" in the first 12 hours. There doesn't seem to be any way of knowing whether the user manually revoked access (intentful) or it happened because of a password reset (side-effect).

Apart from those, there's a myriad of other potential causes that could trigger the error:

3. **Server clock/time is out of sync**
4. **Not authorized for offline access**
5. **Throttled by Google**
6. **Using expired refresh tokens**
7. **User has been inactive for 6 months**
8. **Use service worker email instead of client ID**
9. **Too many access tokens in short time**
10. **Client SDK might be outdated**
11. **Incorrect/incomplete refresh token**

[I've written a short article](https://medium.com/timekit/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35#.eqa5iwbkt) summarizing each item with some debugging guidance to help find the culprit.

Comment: Another scenario is if you try to get tokens multiple times form the same auth code.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, simply revoking the app by accident. Then had to rerun the refreshToken.php through terminal to generate another authorization code and then replace the refreshToken everywhere for this clientID.

Comment: In my case, I changed my password a month ago. I found out that I need to give permission to the app again and get the new refresh token

Comment: I don't have any of the above 11 items but I still got it.

Answer (score 86):

I ran into this same problem despite specifying the "offline" `access_type` in my request as per bonkydog's answer.  Long story short I found that the solution described here worked for me:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/4uNaJtquxCs

In essence, when you add an OAuth2 Client in your Google API's console Google will give you a "Client ID" and an "Email address" (assuming you select "webapp" as your client type).  And despite Google's misleading naming conventions, they expect you to send the "Email address" as the value of the `client_id` parameter when you access their OAuth2 API's.

This applies when calling both of these URL's:

- https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Note that the call to the first URL will *succeed* if you call it with your "Client ID" instead of your "Email address".  However using the code returned from that request will not work when attempting to get a bearer token from the second URL.  Instead you will get an 'Error 400' and an "invalid_grant" message.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous: Especially the part where it works with the client_id if you get an initial refresh token. Googles API and their documentation is a mess.

Comment: I was banging my head against this issue for so many hours. I never expected that 'client_id' was not what was expected for the 'client_id' field. Except the occasional time when you do get a refresh_token and it does work. Pretty sure the words I have for google at the moment can't be said on SO.

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that this behavior changed in the last couple of days?  I made this change to use the email address form a couple of months ago and everything starting working fine again for a while, but now all of a sudden all calls to both URLs are failing with "The OAuth client was not found."  I switched back to the client ID form and it works again, but now I'm not sure if this is going to start breaking in the way it did before.

Comment: Hi there.. Im unable to find that "email" address you guys are talking about. this is what I have in my console --> https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CVVcEBWUwAAIiCy.png:large

Comment: Where is that email Address? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I guess something changed here. Look at this doc : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

Comment: Never trust Google documentation.  Crapiest documentation and APIs come from Google, the most valuable company in the world. I had to spend countless hours to use Google API. There were issues after issues and then their own .Net libraries for different APIs not being compiling together due to differing dependency issues and all. The code now works well for most users but for some users I still get invalid_grant, invalid_credentials etc. for no particular reasons.

Comment: I receive invalid_grant exception for some users while other users work fine.  So if there was something wrong with the code, it should have not worked for 95% users.  All these comments as to how they fixed this issue are bogus.  The fact here is that Google API is one of the crappiest product I have encountered.

Comment: I can only confirm that I too have had these issues... some users get invalid_grant while the calls work fine for others. Using the clientid from developer console, not the email.

Comment: Replacing the `client_id` with the user's email gives a `invalid_client` error. This answer seems outdated.

Answer (score 52):

If you're testing this out in postman / insomnia and are just trying to get it working, hint: the server auth code (code parameter) is only good once. Meaning if you stuff up any of the other parameters in the request and get back a 400, you'll need to use a new server auth code or you'll just get another 400.

Comment: Trying the same code countless time before found this answer. You saved my day. It's strange that this answer not shown on top. I need to scroll down to find this.

Comment: This was painful to learn, and to not have been more obvious in the Google docs is ... disappointing at the very least.

Comment: This was the problem for me too. Thank you. Chasing my tail with the top voted answer, but none in that list covers it!

Answer (score 9):

We tried so many things, and in the end the issue was that the client had turned
"Less Secure App Access" off in their Google Account settings.

To turn this on:

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/ and manage account
2. Go to the Security tab
3. Turn Less secure app access on

[image]

I hope this saves someone some time!

Comment: Direct link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps 
 It's not working if two-factor authorization is enabled.

Comment: Google stop less secure

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem. For me, I fixed this by using Email Address (the string that ends with ...@developer.gserviceaccount.com) instead of Client ID for client_id parameter value. The naming set by Google is confusing here.

Comment: This is the same answer given by @aroth more than a year earlier

Answer (score 6):

My issue was that I used this URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

When I should have used this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

This was testing a service account which wanted offline access to the [Storage engine](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

Answer (score 6):

This is a silly answer, but the problem for me was that I failed to realize I already had been issued an active oAuth token for my google user which I failed to store. The solution in this case is to go to the api console and reset the client secret.

There are numerous other answers on SO to this effect for example
[Reset Client Secret OAuth2 - Do clients need to re-grant access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088202/reset-client-secret-oauth2-do-clients-need-to-re-grant-access)

Answer (score 5):

Solved by removing all Authorized redirect URIs in Google console for the project.
I use server side flow when you use 'postmessage' as redirect URI

Answer (score 4):

Using a Android clientId (no client_secret) I was getting the following error response:

```
{
 "error": "invalid_grant",
 "error_description": "Missing code verifier."
}
```

I cannot find any documentation for the field 'code_verifier' but I discovered if you set it to equal values in both the authorization and token requests it will remove this error.  I'm not sure what the intended value should be or if it should be secure. It has some minimum length (16? characters) but I found setting to `null` also works.

I am using AppAuth for the authorization request in my Android client which has a `setCodeVerifier()` function.

```
AuthorizationRequest authRequest = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
                                    serviceConfiguration,
                                    provider.getClientId(),
                                    ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
                                    provider.getRedirectUri()
                            )
                            .setScope(provider.getScope())
                            .setCodeVerifier(null)
                            .build();
```

Here is an example token request in node:

```
request.post(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
  { form: {
    'code': '4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'code_verifier': null,
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret': null,
    'redirect_uri': 'com.domain.app:/oauth2redirect',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
  } },
  function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('Success!');
    } else {
      console.log(response.statusCode + ' ' + error);
    }

    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

I tested and this works with both `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` and `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`.

If you are using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest` instead:

```
final GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest req = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    TRANSPORT,
                    JSON_FACTORY,
                    getClientId(),
                    getClientSecret(),
                    code,
                    redirectUrl
);
req.set("code_verifier", null);          
GoogleTokenResponse response = req.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two major reasons for **[invalid_grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2)** error which you have to take care prior to the POST request for Refresh Token and Access Token.

1. Request header must contain "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2. Your request payload should be url encoded Form Data, don't send as json object.

[RFC 6749 OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) defined **invalid_grant** as:
*The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.*

I found another good article, [here](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) you will find many other reasons for this error.

https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

Comment: Did you mean to post two nearly identical answers? You might want to delete this one because the other has an additional line.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was trying to use gcloud APIs through a Go program running locally. I recently changed my user's password so I first tried `gcloud auth login` but it kept outputing the same `invalid_grant` error.

The catch is that you are not interacting directly with the api, your code is, so you have to use `gcloud auth application-default login` instead. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message 'invalid_grant' and it was because the 
**authResult['code']**
send from client side javascript was not received correctly on the server.

Try to output it back from the server to see if it is correct and not an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Try change your url for requst to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have to remove a stale/invalid OAuth response.

Credit: [node.js google oauth2 sample stopped working invalid_grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995046/node-js-google-oauth2-sample-stopped-working-invalid-grant)

**Note**: An OAuth response will also become invalid if the password used in the initial authorization has been changed.

If in a bash environment, you can use the following to remove the stale response:

`rm /Users/<username>/.credentials/<authorization.json>`

Answer (score 3):

The code you obtain in the URL after user consent has a very short expiry. Please obtain the code again and attempt to get access token within seconds (you have to hurry) and it should work. I can't find out the expiry period of code but it's literally very short.

Comment: Didn't see it any of the docs! You made my night shorter <3

Answer (score 2):

if you are using scribe library, for example to set up the offline mode, like bonkydog suggested.
here is the code:

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(Google2Api.class).apiKey(clientId).apiSecret(apiSecret)
                .callback(callbackUrl).scope(SCOPE).offline(true)
                .build();
```

https://github.com/codolutions/scribe-java/

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a callback URL that was different from the original request.
So, **callback URL should be the same** for auth request and code exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I my case I just didn't read the [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens) properly because I was trying to do `const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(accessToken);`
every time to get an authorized client instance but for the subsequent requests you only need to include the `refresh_token` you store after the first user auth.

```js
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: `STORED_REFRESH_TOKEN`
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if your redirect_url is not the same as the one you have when creating the token on Google Gloud. So make sure it's correct

Answer (score 2):

None of the answer worked for me. After calling

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=<CALLBACK_URL_YOU_SET_ON_GOOGLE>&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=<YOUR CLIENT ID>&scope=openid%20email%20profile&access_type=offline
```

I was getting response url in return which had `code` value

```
4%2F0ARtbsJoGfJYFT6Cy1VpPiONgYV1vIzVhGtTK9MvyQLZfuGv_sAPDRDOzqGkRu07qOIxBfg
```

Instead of decoding the the url received I copied this value and passed to my app API and got the reported error `invalid_grant`.
`%2F` in the above code should be replaced by `/`. It should be

```
4/0ARtbsJoGfJYFT6Cy1VpPiONgYV1vIzVhGtTK9MvyQLZfuGv_sAPDRDOzqGkRu07qOIxBfg
```

Note that this `code` works only once.

**Lesson:** Always decode the received url!

Comment: Just to add, a string can be decoded in JS/NodeJS using the built-in `decodeURIComponent(string)`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 1):

in this site
[console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

this console board select your project input the oath url.
the oauth callback url will redirect when the oauth success

Answer (score 1):

After considering and trying all of the other ways here, here's how I solved the issue in nodejs with the `googleapis` module in conjunction with the `request` module, which I used to fetch the tokens instead of the provided `getToken()` method:

```
const request = require('request');

//SETUP GOOGLE AUTH
var google = require('googleapis');
const oAuthConfigs = rootRequire('config/oAuthConfig')
const googleOAuthConfigs = oAuthConfigs.google

//for google OAuth: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var googleOAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
    process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID || googleOAuthConfigs.clientId, 
    process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET || googleOAuthConfigs.clientSecret, 
    process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL || googleOAuthConfigs.callbackUrl);

/* generate a url that asks permissions for Google+ and Google Calendar scopes
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#monitoringv3*/
var googleOAuth2ClientScopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
];

var googleOAuth2ClientRedirectURL = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL || googleOAuthConfigs.callbackUrl; 

var googleOAuth2ClientAuthUrl = googleOAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline', // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
  scope: googleOAuth2ClientScopes // If you only need one scope you can pass it as string
});

//AFTER SETUP, THE FOLLOWING IS FOR OBTAINING TOKENS FROM THE AUTHCODE


        const ci = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID || googleOAuthConfigs.clientId
        const cs = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET || googleOAuthConfigs.clientSecret
        const ru = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL || googleOAuthConfigs.callbackUrl
        var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(ci, cs, ru);

        var hostUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com";
        hostUrl += '/oauth2/v4/token?code=' + authCode + '&client_id=' + ci + '&client_secret=' + cs + '&redirect_uri=' + ru + '&grant_type=authorization_code',
        request.post({url: hostUrl}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, data) {
            // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
            if(!err) {
                //SUCCESS! We got the tokens
                const tokens = JSON.parse(data)
                oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

                //AUTHENTICATED PROCEED AS DESIRED.
                googlePlus.people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client }, function(err, response) {
                // handle err and response
                    if(!err) {
                        res.status(200).json(response);
                    } else {
                        console.error("/google/exchange 1", err.message);
                        handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to retrieve google person");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("/google/exchange 2", err.message);
                handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get access tokens", err.code);
            }
        });
```

I simply use `request` to make the api request via HTTP as described here: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Answer (score 1):

For future folks... I read many articles and blogs but had luck with solution below...

```
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
      new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
          new NetHttpTransport(),
          JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
          "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
          clientId,
          clientSecret,
          authCode,
          "") //Redirect Url
     .setScopes(scopes)
     .setGrantType("authorization_code")
     .execute();
```

[This](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) blog depicts different cases in which "invalid_grant" error comes.

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

for me I had to make sure that the `redirect_uri` is an exact match to the one in the developer console `Authorised redirect URIs`, that fixed it for me, I was able to debug and know what exactly was the issue after switching from
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`

I got a proper error:

```
{"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",  "error_description": "Bad Request"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after enabling a new service API on the Google console and trying to use the previously made credentials.

To fix the problem, I had to go back to the credential page, clicking on the credential name, and clicking "Save" **again**. After that, I could authenticate just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was in my code. Mistakenly I've tried to initiate client 2 times with the same tokens. If none of the answers above helped make sure you do not generate 2 instances of the client.

My code before the fix:

```
def gc_service
      oauth_client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
      oauth_client.code = params[:code]
      response = oauth_client.fetch_access_token!
      session[:authorization] = response
      oauth_client.update!(session[:authorization])

      gc_service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
      gc_service.authorization = oauth_client

      gc_service
    end
```

```
primary_calendar_id = gc_service.list_calendar_lists.items.select(&:primary).first.id

gc_service.insert_acl(primary_calendar_id, acl_rule_object, send_notifications: false)
```

as soon as I change it to (use only one instance):

```
@gc_service = gc_service
primary_calendar_id = @gc_service.list_calendar_lists.items.select(&:primary).first.id

@gc_service.insert_acl(primary_calendar_id, acl_rule_object, send_notifications: false)
```

it fixed my issues with grant type.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issues was I had multiple clients in my project and I am pretty sure this is perfectly alright, but  I deleted all the client for that project and created a new one and all started working for me ( Got this idea fro WP_SMTP plugin help support forum) I am not able to find out that link for reference

Answer (score 1):

If you are sanitizing user input (For example, `$_GET["code"]` in php) Make sure you don't accidentally replace something in the code.

The regex I am using is now `/[^A-Za-z0-9\/-]/`

Answer (score 1):

Look at this https://dev.to/risafj/beginner-s-guide-to-oauth-understanding-access-tokens-and-authorization-codes-2988

First you need an access_token:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];

$clientid = "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$clientsecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=".urlencode($clientid)."&client_secret=".urlencode($clientsecret)."&code=".urlencode($code)."&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=". urlencode("https://yourdomain.com"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$server_output = json_decode($server_output);
$access_token = $server_output->access_token;
$refresh_token = $server_output->refresh_token;
$expires_in = $server_output->expires_in;
```

Safe the Access Token and the Refresh Token and the expire_in, in a Database. The Access Token expires after $expires_in seconds. Than you need to grab a new Access Token (and safe it in the Database) with the following Request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=".urlencode($clientid)."&client_secret=".urlencode($clientsecret)."&refresh_token=".urlencode($refresh_token)."&grant_type=refresh_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$server_output = json_decode($server_output);
$access_token = $server_output->access_token;
$expires_in = $server_output->expires_in;
```

Bear in Mind to add the redirect_uri Domain to your Domains in your Google Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials in the Tab "OAuth 2.0-Client-IDs". There you find also your Client-ID and Client-Secret.

Answer (score 1):

There is a undocumented timeout between when you first redirect the user to the google authentication page (and get back a code), and when you take the returned code and post it to the token url. It works fine for me with the actual google supplied client_id as opposed to an "undocumented email address". I just needed to start the process again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was caused by subsequent `getToken` calls with the same code.

Namely, in NestJS my callback endpoint was decorated with `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))` and I tried to call `getToken` in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

***Creation of the new Credentials key under:***

[image]

***Was the honey for me.***

from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got to remove web cookies before testing Google connect link Api.

Answer (score 0):

**Generating refresh and access token:**

Replace the essential values (code, client_id, client_secret) inside payload.

```
let payload = {
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code:'********FDLJli-DFJNLDLfKJ',
  client_id: '******.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'GOCS*******m5Qzg',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
};

axios
  .post(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, payload, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
    },
  })
  .then((res: any) => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .then((response: any) => {
    console.log('refresh token: ', response);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('err: ', err));
```

You will get a response like this:

```
{
    access_token: "********KAjJZmv4xLvbAIHey",
    expires_in: 3599,
    id_token: "***************VeM7cfmgbvVIg",
    refresh_token: "***************VeM7cfmgbvVIg",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly openid 
            .....
            .....
            https://mail.google.com/",
    token_type: "Bearer",
}
```

Save your refresh and access token.
Now you can use refresh token to generate new access token!
Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@sacshaurov05/login-with-google-oauth-get-refresh-and-access-token-regenerate-access-token-on-your-react-app-101677118ac7) on how you can integrate this on your react application. You can check this out for more details.

> Note: Do not request again and again for refresh token. They provide it only once. I faced some issues while requesting refresh token for more than 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()` and get the `invalid_grant` error then you can try to re-login with `gcloud auth application-default login`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and eventually learned that the issue was on my side, not Google's. My locally-running UI had `React.StrictMode` enabled, which caused the relevant OAuth callback circuitry to render twice, failing the second time the same code was used.

If your network tab shows two requests, the first of which succeeds, perhaps this is your issue as well.