# invalid grant when trying to authorize a server to server type application in ruby for accessing Google Calendar

Tags: ruby, sinatra, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create an app for myself that just directly connects to my calendar... but I never want to be involved with re-authenticating. I just want to code the authentication once and be done with it.

The Auth code is as follows:

```
key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, PASSWORD)
asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 
    key)
@client = Google::APIClient.new
@client.authorization = asserter.authorize#(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
@client
```

My `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_...PKCS .` file is in the root of the directory along with my Sinatra app.
I have enabled the Google Calendar API on my gmail account.

I've been looking at a method of authentication here: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/ (under authorization, where it talks about server to server communication)

```
$ ruby server.rb 
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/faraday-0.8.4/lib/faraday/utils.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant KeyMap
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/faraday-0.8.4/lib/faraday/utils.rb:177: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_SEP
W, [2013-01-15T09:52:11.371122 #28607]  WARN -- : Google::APIClient - Please provide :application_name and :application_version when initializing the client
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/signet-0.4.4/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:869:in `fetch_access_token': Authorization failed.  Server message: (Signet::AuthorizationError)
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/signet-0.4.4/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:882:in `fetch_access_token!'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/google-api-client-0.6.1/lib/google/api_client/auth/jwt_asserter.rb:116:in `authorize'
    from server.rb:32:in `build_client'
    from server.rb:38
```

What could the issue be? Why am I getting this error? - especially since I've pretty much copied the code from the google gem's site.

UPDATE:

found this:

[invalid_grant trying to get oAuth token from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google)

says I should do this:
"Make sure you specify access_type=offline in your request."

how do I do this with the ruby gem? without completely re-doing the http requests?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a connection to Drive. Just started this morning.

Comment: have you reached a resolution?

Comment: any luck? having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code, which is similar except the last line, which should have the email of the user who actually owns the calendar (you). I assume the service account email is not your email.

```
client_asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
    config['client_email'],
    PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE,
    key
)
$client.authorization = client_asserter.authorize(config['user_email'])
```

Also, make sure you crate the service account properly. I used this guide: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation, which is for Domain API, but the first part should be the same.

Also, don't you need another scope for authentication?

Here is a full example (ruby) that I got to work for me: https://github.com/admitriyev/propellant/blob/master/main.rb