# OAuth2 Google Service Account invalid_grant

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

The keys I've posted here are from a container I've deleted, but were all valid keys that have been provided to me by Google.

I'm attempting to implement: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData

The uploadData function works fine, and everything is accepted in Google Analytics. My problem lies with Google's OAuth2: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization

From what I've gathered, for the end-point I wish to hit, I must use an OAuth2 token, and cannot use an api key. The request doesn't accept ?key={api}, and only Bearer Authorization. Using the Service Account request, all I receive is invalid_grant. I've updated my clocks and does various miss-matches of values to no avail. Mind you, with similar keys, all other workflows work, but I don't wish to have user interaction as this is a background task.

json for key data (provided by Google):
`{
  "private_key_id": "825119b6ab0eabf2029a4e1cf562fa88090736a0",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\n5ARPrKY4iXG7UoU\u003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "42064665633-fbbnb79350js2h22e8k1s3h9t52rursu@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "42064665633-fbbnb79350js2h22e8k1s3h9t52rursu.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}`

The other 2 associated tags to create `{Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}` are:

```
$header = [
    'alg' => 'RS256',
    'typ' => 'JWT'
];
$body = [
    "iss" => "42064665633-fbbnb79350js2h22e8k1s3h9t52rursu.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scope" => "https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/analytics https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/analytics.edit",
    "aud" => "https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/token",
    "exp" => strtotime('1 hour'),
    "iat" => strtotime('now')
];
$header = base64_encode(json_encode($header));
$body = base64_encode(json_encode($body));
```

The signature is defined as the `private_key` in the google docs link above. I've tried every excerpt of information from Java questions pertaining to this method of authentication, from escaping slashes (shown above), to omitting fields.

What have I done wrong/left out that causes `{"error" : "invalid_grant"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a proper solution to getting JWT Service Accounts to work, I'm now storing a refresh token for the web route. Everything is working well, it's just a lot of information I need to keep in my config.yml file that I'd rather not.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with oauth2 for objective c but here is my best shot at handling this:

1. [invalid_grant trying to get oAuth token from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google)
2. Your internal clock may be out of sync with the google clock or your refresh token may be refreshed too much.
3. Make sure your client key and secret are up to date, if not revoke them and get new ones.
4. In PHP, make sure you are using the POST request.

Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication

Comment: I've updated my ntp clock previously, and I've run these queries on a staging server directly via curl. To just test the output I'm running the exact `curl url -d 'data'` query Google provides. This set has never returned anything correctly so I doubt there is a refresh token. I've made new keys to test with anyway. `access_type` is not permitted for this workflow. Is there anything else you remember doing to use Google's OAuth2 implementation for a Service Account?

Comment: Firstly, try to use google's oauth2 playground to test your code to make sure that that is it because curl can have some unknown issues as well. Well as I remember it, any google OAuth2 that uses access tokens has to perform the "oauth dance" as they call it. https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/oauth. After that, I have no idea lol :(.