# Reset Client Secret OAuth2 - Do clients need to re-grant access?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

As a security best practice, when an engineer/intern leaves the team, I want to reset the client secret of my Google API console project.

The project has OAuth2 access granted by a bunch of people, and I need to ensure that those (grants as well as refresh tokens) will not stop working. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find documentation that explicitly states this.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes.** Client Secret reset will immediately (in Google OAuth 2.0, there may be a few minutes delay) invalidate any authorization "code" or refresh token issued to the client.

Client secret reset is a countermeasure against abuse of revealed client secrets for private clients. So it makes sense to require re-grant once the secret is reset.

I did not find any Google document states this explicitly either. But my practice proves that reset will impact users, also you can do a test on it.

And in our work, we programmers do not touch product's secret, we have test clients. Only a very few product ops guys can touch that. So I think you need to try your best to narrow down the visibility of the secret in your team. Rest is not a good way.

Comment: If this answer was correct in 2014, it's no longer correct now. I can confirm that resetting the google client secret DOES NOT invalidate existing client access/refresh tokens.