# Is there any way make account picker UI appear as fast as possible

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

Currently, I'm migrating from *API Client Library for Java* to *Drive API for Android*

However, compared with *API Client Library for Java*'s, I realize the account picker from *Drive API for Android* are very slow. **Sometimes, it takes up to 5 seconds waiting time.**

### Very fast (API Client Library for Java)

```
private static final GoogleAccountCredential googleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, 
    Arrays.asList(
        DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA,
        // Legacy. Shall be removed after a while...
        DriveScopes.DRIVE
    )
);

startActivityForResult(googleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), RequestCode.REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER_LOAD_FROM_CLOUD);
```

[image]

This account picker appears almost instantly.

---

### Very slow (Drive API for Android)

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}
```

[image]

Usually, when I invoke the account picker for the first time, it takes quite a long time to wait. Sometimes, the waiting time can take up to 5 seconds.

I understand that our application code invoke Google Play Services via IPC. Hence, there might be some slowness. However, I don't expect it to be as slow as up to 5 seconds.

***Is there any thing I can do, to make account picker UI appear as fast as possible?***

Comment: It has been discussed [here already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701380/how-can-i-enforce-googleapiclient-to-prompt-account-chooser-ui-each-time-i-call/34706726#34706726). Try to use account picker (startActivityForResult(....)) with 'setAccountName(email)'. I did not experience any delays.

Comment: Thanks. I also don't experience delay by using account picker from `startActivityForResult`. Have you ever try to use `result.startResolutionForResult` to show account picker? Do you experience any delay? As I'm not sure whether the delay is only happen in my device, or it is a common case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described by @seanpj in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706726/72437

```
startActivityForResult(AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null,
    null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, null, null, null, null),
    REQ_ACCPICK);
```

will be much faster.

One of the reason, it doesn't show your profile picture in the pop up dialog. I believe those profile pictures required network activities, which make the process slow.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following (I don't use `addScope`):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .build();
```

The account picker appears fast (my phone: Motorola, API 16).

Comment: Thanks. Going to try it tonight tonight. I was wondering can you help to experiment my code? As I wish to know whether the slowness is only happening in my own device (Nexus 5), or it happens in most of the devices?

Comment: I tried your code, nothing display, except using `.enableAutoManage`. The code I tried `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)                
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                //.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                //.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();   

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();`. It displays fast too.

Comment: That's pretty weird. Maybe you need to wait for longer time like 10 seconds? (Yes. It takes that long sometimes) As, the code is merely copy n paste from official Android Drive API example - https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java#L80

Comment: Opps sorry. I forget, the UI is triggered by `result.startResolutionForResult`. I had modified the code.

Comment: I tried your modified code, the picker displays fast too, IMO, you can test with some other phones or perhaps even another faster network (wifi, 3G)? :)