# First mail is auto-selected when login by Google Play Game Services on Android App

Tags: android, google-play-games

I want my users to login using Google Play Game Services to play my game. And I did it by this guide: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init . Everything is ok.

There is only 1 small "problem". If users have many mail on their phone, first mail will be selected by default when they login. Sign-in flow will be like this:

[Open App] --> [Dialog with Denied/Allow button (with first mail)] --> if we choose DENIED, [Mail chooser dialog] will be shown.

**Question 1 is**: is that default behavior of Google Play Game Services?

What I want in sign-in flow is:

[Open App] --> [Mail chooser dialog] --> [Dialog with Denied/Allow button (with selected mail)]

**Question 2 is**: can I do that and how?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the [`AccountPicker`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker) for you to be able to select accounts. You'll then use the result from the `onActivityResult` method to get the email and set it on the `GoogleApiClientBuilder.setAccountName`.

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701380/how-can-i-enforce-googleapiclient-to-prompt-account-chooser-ui-each-time-i-call) for more information about it.

Happy coding!

Comment: before i ask this question, i already tried solution in that topic, but AccountPicker is not the default mail chooser in Google play game services. Its not like first picture in that topic. Its just a black and simple dialog, with a radio button next by email address. thank you anyway for your reply