# Google Analytics Oauth invalid grant_type

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am using this library : https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP

I am using "service account" method to auth, I generated the p12key, put the ID and email from Google dev console, but I have this error :

> { ["http_code"]=> int(400) ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_grant" }

I checked on the web, the time on my server is correct, and I look at the library, it use the email as ID, as I saw here : [invalid_grant trying to get oAuth token from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google)

What must I do ? there is no information about this error on Google documentation, which is a mess...

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually my server clock was not set properly. I just run :

```
apt-get install ntp
```

And it works !