# node.js google oauth2 sample stopped working invalid_grant

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a program that uses the google calendar api,
so I used the quick start from [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) and it worked.
but recently the same code stopped working and gave me the following error.

```
The API returned an error: Error: invalid_grant
```

This means that the error came from

```
103: calendar.events.list()
```

What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you getting invalid_grant error when using refresh token? If that is the case, check this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization. It could probably due to server's clock not in sync with NTP or refresh token limit has exceeded.

Comment: i had a service account working for months and I started getting invalid_grant a couple of days ago...

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me when I changed my account password. To fix it I had to delete the credentials file that gets referenced in the quick start here:

```
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';
```

This should do the trick.

```
rm /Users/<username>/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
```

Comment: Just 1 google search result for this problem but, boom! the correct solution. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thank you! Stating the obvious: you need to adjust the name of the credentials file depending on which quickstart you're using. For example: youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json.