# To what extent do the Google OAuth 2.0 APIs support RFC7636?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am looking for concrete information regarding the state of RFC7636 (proof key for OAuth token exchanges) in Google's OAuth2 APIs.

Google exposes an OAuth 2.0 and OIDC provider API where access tokens can be obtained. There is a proposed standard described in RFC7636 for using proof keys in token exchanges which we have started using in our integrations with major identity providers. Some accept the proof key, others ignore it; Google seems to be aware of it but fails to validate the proof key. I have not been able to find any mention of this wrt Google.

In concrete terms, when following the authorization code flow of OAuth 2.0 with Google as the provider we generate a random number, hash it using SHA256, base64 URL encode it, and then pass it to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth as parameter "code_challenge" and "code_challenge_method" as per the spec.

The endpoint accepts the parameters and issues an authorization token as usual. When obtaining the access token we call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token with the code_verifier; the endpoint returns the following HTTP 400 error which suggests that there is some awareness of code verifiers:
     { 
       "error": "invalid_grant", 
       "error_description": "Missing code verifier."
     }

Google's OAuth documentation at developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 does not mention any of these parameters; the API playground does not extend to playing with the OAuth2 auth and token endpoints. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm having the exact same problem: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Missing code verifier." }, using the iOS SDK AppAuth, hitting the exact same endpoints you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem using AppAuth and an Android clientId. In order to fix it I had to set a matching 'code_verifier' field on both the authorization and token requests.  You can find a more in depth description in this post: [invalid_grant trying to get oAuth token from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google/43106508#43106508)