# OAuth2 / WebAPI throwing Invalid Grant when logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm building a SPA using AngularJS for the client side and the login information is being sent to a ASP.NET WebAPI as an AJAX post.  I have the following code in Startup.Auth.cs for the API.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container)
    {
        var oauthProvider = container.Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();
        var oauthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/RHDevAuth/login"),
            Provider = oauthProvider,
            AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
            SystemClock = new SystemClock()

        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(oauthOptions);
    }
```

I'm sending a request to the API that contains the following:

```
Request Headers: 
Http: //mySite/api/login
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 76
Request Body:
username=steve123%40gmail.com%2C&password=Test222%2C&grant_type=password
```

The server is responding with an { error: invalid_grant }.

Everything works fine when I run it from local host.  However, I get the error when I deploy it to a hosted server account.

What can I do to make this work for either environment?

Comment: this might be help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google

Comment: Not very helpful. It dealt with issues specific to Google API more then anything.