# invalid_grant with high volume of logins and googleapis Node.js package

Tags: google-oauth

We're doing a high volume of "getToken" requests (supplying a code) using the OAuth2 client from the "googleapis" npm package (version 14.2.0).

Out of **84,940** successful requests within a 24 hour period, **290** fail with the notorious "invalid_grant" error.  We've checked everything found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google) , but are still experiencing these errors.  Obviously this is a very small error rate (**< 0.5%**), probably within acceptable range if these were general errors from Google (500).

1. Can "invalid_grant" also represent general errors?  If so, we'd be inclined to just ignore these errors as part of the reality of doing so many logins.
2. If not, are there ways to dig deeper into the issue?