# How to fix the "Malformed auth code" when trying to refreshToken on the second attempt?

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, cordova-plugins, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm developping an Android App with Angular and Cordova plugins and I want to integrate it with Google Authentication.
I have installed the [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)  and I have successfully integrated into the application.
When the user logs in, I get a response where I can get accessToken, profile user information and refreshToken.

Now I want to implement a feature to refresh the token without disturbing the user with a new prompt screen every hour.

I have managed to renew accessToken, but it only works the first time

I have used these two ways:

1. Sending a curl request with the following data

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=YYYYYYYYYYYY&grant_type=authorization_code' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

2. Implementing it on the server side using the Google API Client Library for Java and following mainly these [code](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.html)

The point is that when the user logs in for the first time (using the cordova-plugin-googleplus), I receive a refreshToken with this format

```
4/rgFU-hxw9QSbfdj3ppQ4sqDjK2Dr3m_YU_UMCqcveUgjIa3voawbN9TD6SVLShedTPveQeZWDdR-Sf1nFrss1hc
```

If after a while I try to refresh the token in any of the above ways I get a successful response with a new accessToken, and a new refreshToken. And that new refreshToken has this other format

```
1/FTSUyYTgU2AG8K-ZsgjVi6pExdmpZejXfoYIchp9KuhtdknEMd6uYCfqMOoX2f85J
```

In the second attempt to renew the token, I replace the token with the one returned in the first request

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=1/FTSUyYTgU2AG8K-ZsgjVi6pExdmpZejXfoYIchp9KuhtdknEMd6uYCfqMOoX2f85J&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=YYYYYYYYYYYY&grant_type=authorization_code' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

But this time, both ways (Curl and Java) I am getting the same error.

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Malformed auth code."
}
```

I read on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19041051/12155976) that was a problem to specify the clientId as an email, but I have not discovered how to solve it either because the first login it's done with the client id 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com' and if I set an email from the google accounts it says that is an "Unknown Oauth Client"

I hope any can help me with this, as I'm stuck for several days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I achieved refreshing the access token as times as needed. The problem was a misconception of how it works the Google Api.

The first time to update the token, it is needed to call this endpoint with these parameters and setting as {{refreshToken}} the value obtained from the response of the Consent Screen call (serverAuthCode)

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code={{refreshToken}}&client_id={{googleClientId}}&client_secret={{googleClientSecret}}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

After the first refresh, any update to the token needs to be call to this other endpoint by setting as {{tokenUpdated}} the attribute {{refresh_token}} obtained from the response of the first call.

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?refresh_token={{tokenUpdated}}&client_id={{googleClientId}}&client_secret={{googleClientSecret}}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Here I show you an example of my AuthenticationService

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {


static AUTH_INFO_GOOGLE = 'auth-info-google';
static CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX-XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
static CLIENT_SECRET = 'SecretPasswordClientId';


public authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private googlePlus: GooglePlus) {

  }

public isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationState.value;
}

public logout(): Promise<void> {
    this.authenticationState.next(false);   
    return this.googlePlus.disconnect()
    .then(msg => {
      console.log('User logged out: ' + msg);
    }, err => {
      console.log('User already disconected');
    }); 
}

/**
* Performs the login
*/
public async login(): Promise<any> {
    return this.openGoogleConsentScreen().then(async (user) => {
      console.log(' ServerAuth Code: ' + user.serverAuthCode);
      user.updated = false;
      await this.setData(AuthenticationService.AUTH_INFO_GOOGLE, JSON.stringify(user));
      this.authenticationState.next(true);
      // Do more staff after successfully login
    }, err => {
        this.authenticationState.next(false);
        console.log('An error ocurred in the login process: ' + err);
        console.log(err);
    });

}

  /**
   * Gets the Authentication Token
   */
public async getAuthenticationToken(): Promise<string> {
      return this.getAuthInfoGoogle()
        .then(auth => {
          if (this.isTokenExpired(auth)) {
            return this.refreshToken(auth);
          } else {
            return 'Bearer ' + auth.accessToken;
          }
        });
}



private async openGoogleConsentScreen(): Promise<any> {
  return this.googlePlus.login({
    // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
    'scopes': 'profile email openid',
    'webClientId': AuthenticationService.CLIENT_ID,
    'offline': true
  });
}

private isTokenExpired(auth: any): Boolean {
    const expiresIn = auth.expires - (Date.now() / 1000);
     const extraSeconds = 60 * 59 + 1;
    // const extraSeconds = 0;
    const newExpiration = expiresIn - extraSeconds;
     console.log('Token expires in ' + newExpiration + ' seconds. Added ' + extraSeconds + ' seconds for debugging purpouses');
    return newExpiration < 0;
}

private async refreshToken(auth: any): Promise<any> {
      console.log('The authentication token has expired. Calling for renewing');
      if (auth.updated) {
        auth = await this.requestGoogleRefreshToken(auth.serverAuthCode, auth.userId, auth.email);
      } else {
        auth = await this.requestGoogleAuthorizationCode(auth.serverAuthCode, auth.userId, auth.email);
      }
      await this.setData(AuthenticationService.AUTH_INFO_GOOGLE, JSON.stringify(auth));
      return 'Bearer ' + auth.accessToken;
}


private getAuthInfoGoogle(): Promise<any> {
    return this.getData(AuthenticationService.AUTH_INFO_GOOGLE)
    .then(oauthInfo => {
      return JSON.parse(oauthInfo);
    }, err => {
      this.clearStorage();
      throw err;
    });
}

private async requestGoogleAuthorizationCode(serverAuthCode: string, userId: string, email: string): Promise<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('code', serverAuthCode);
    params = params.set('client_id', AuthenticationService.CLIENT_ID);
    params = params.set('client_secret', AuthenticationService.CLIENT_SECRET);
    params = params.set('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
    const options = {
      headers: headers,
      params: params
    };
    const url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
    const renewalTokenRequestPromise: Promise<any> = this.http.post(url, {}, options).toPromise()
      .then((response: any) => {
        const auth: any = {};
        auth.accessToken = response.access_token;
        console.log('RefreshToken: ' + response.refresh_token);
        auth.serverAuthCode = response.refresh_token;
        auth.expires = Date.now() / 1000 + response.expires_in;
        auth.userId = userId;
        auth.email = email;
        auth.updated = true;
        return auth;
      }, (error) => {
        console.error('Error renewing the authorization code: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        return {};
      });
    return await renewalTokenRequestPromise;
}

private async requestGoogleRefreshToken(serverAuthCode: string, userId: string, email: string): Promise<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('refresh_token', serverAuthCode);
    params = params.set('client_id', AuthenticationService.CLIENT_ID);
    params = params.set('client_secret', AuthenticationService.CLIENT_SECRET);
    params = params.set('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
    const options = {
      headers: headers,
      params: params
    };
    const url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
    const renewalTokenRequestPromise: Promise<any> = this.http.post(url, {}, options).toPromise()
      .then((response: any) => {
        const auth: any = {};
        auth.accessToken = response.access_token;
        console.log('RefreshToken: ' + serverAuthCode);
        auth.serverAuthCode = serverAuthCode;
        auth.expires = Date.now() / 1000 + response.expires_in;
        auth.userId = userId;
        auth.email = email;
        auth.updated = true;
        return auth;
      }, (error) => {
        console.error('Error renewing refresh token: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        return {};
      });
    return await renewalTokenRequestPromise;
}

private setData(key: string, value: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('Store the value at key entry in the DDBB, Cookies, LocalStorage, etc')
}

private getData(key: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log('Retrieve the value from the key entry from DDBB, Cookies, LocalStorage, etc')
}

private clearStorage(): Promise<string> {
    console.log('Remove entries from DDBB, Cookies, LocalStorage, etc related to authentication')
}



}
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case it was pretty stupid: google api changes the auth code coding between requests.

Step 1 - During the first request to obtain tokens google returns quite normal, not encoded string as the code.

Step 2 - During second and N-th request to obtain tokens (if they were not revoked) google returns the auth code as url-encoded. In my case the killing change was '/' -> '%2F'.

Solution:
Always URL-Decode the auth code before exchanging it for the access tokens!

Comment: Yep, the `%2F` part raised my eyebrow but until reading your post I assumed I should blindly accept the code. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Thanks!!! This was the final step for me after 3 days!

Answer (score 7):

This is an Authorization grant flow. To keep it simple that it follows.I request access token for web app.
In my case the killing change was '%2F' to '/'. This should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

u need to decode your code like this

```
    String code = "4%2F0AX************...";
    String decodedCode = "";
    try {
      decodedCode = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(code, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      //do nothing
    }
```

then use decodedCode as param

Answer (score 0):

This is an Authorization grant flow. To keep it simple following are steps that it follows.

1. First request gets authorizatio_code (This one with param authorization_code)
2. Once you receive the code use it to get access_token and refresh_token
3. After a while when access token is expired use the refresh_token from Step 2 to get new access token and new refresh token. (When you use the code from step 1 you will see the error.)

Hope this helps, please change your code and try again.

Comment: Dear Venkatesh, Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless I have followed the steps that you mentioned but they are not different from the one I mentioned previously.
* Step 1: I get this authorization_code from the Cordova Google+ Plugin 
* Step 2: I make the post to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token and receive a refresh token starting with "1/" 
* Step 3: I repeat the same request as in step 2 but changing the refresh_token from the one obtained in step 2

Answer (score 0):

Your codes both have a "/" as their second character. You should probably url-encode it before you put it in a query string.

Answer (score 0):

By adding URLDecode will work. But now it is not working anymore.

Must add `prompt=consent` then only return the refresh token when using authorization code to claim it.