# Google api client "Malformed auth code" in Laravel PHP Merchant project

Tags: php, laravel, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I got a problem with a using the google/apiclient package.
When I trying to get an access_token using auth code from front-end I getting back error form google "Malformed auth code".

The google auth code looks like this one:

*ya29.A0ARrdaM8wqLBvw5yrNa0wDQGPSUvncigERIqtYC_D2tQl2QCYm3rbcthI_om_BcHGFGcDrN6qgUM37zt9ot7OsgEth5XZzZe__ed5B4artd9QNRRK0WD0wnaDl3kjxPKEcp9o53lbloypz7t7KoxO5Mg2PH0*

Thats my code:

```
/**
 * @return Google\Client
 * @throws Google\Exception
 */
public static function getClientHeaders()
{
    $client = new Google\Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(config('services.google.app_name'));
    $client->setAuthConfig(config('merchant.config_file'));
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content');
    return $client;
}

/**
 * @param string $token
 * @return Google\Client
 * @throws Google\Exception
 */
public static function getClient(string $token)
{
    $client = static::getClientHeaders();
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            $creds = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($token);
            if (isset($creds['error'])) {
                abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $creds['error_description']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $client;
}
    
public function getToken()
{
$client = static::getClient(request()->input('access_token'));
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

I am getting an error when I try to run **getToken()** function. Maybe You can see what am I doing wrong :(

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209700/how-to-fix-the-malformed-auth-code-when-trying-to-refreshtoken-on-the-second-a

Comment: I did but my auth code dont have forbidden signs in the body.