# Using maven mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog with GCP Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, google-cloud-platform, liquibase

Has anyone successfully used liquibase maven plugin generateChangeLog against a GCP Mysql Instance.

I have tried the following liquibase.properties

```
url=jdbc:mysql:///global365?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
username=USER
password=PASSWORD
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-changeLog.yml
```

I get the error:
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}

This is not a new application it is successfully running locally and in production with these connection details

Answer (score 1):

From what is see, it is related to google oath credential issue. I found this query that is similar to your issue: [invalid_grant trying to get oAuth token from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google)