# EmailJS authentication problem ( 412 Gmail_API: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. )

Tags: javascript, authentication

I don't know you it's not working. I successfully added my google account with emailjs, but when I try to test it I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYrbu.png) error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to grant the permissions when you log in to Gmail. Need to reconnect. see this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463095/why-am-i-getting-error-while-adding-service-in-emailjs

Answer (score 1):

Please turn off the 2 factor authentication mode off in your gmail account , go back to emailjs referesh it and try again. You will be good to go.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do i need to turn off my 2 factor authentication on my gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party here, but if anyone is still looking for an answer to this, I had to enable the gmail api on the google developer console to get this working. Here's an article that will show you how:
https://mailtrap.io/blog/send-emails-with-gmail-api/